# Fill half of the parent containers height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I need to fill half of the height of a parent without knowing or defining the height of that parent for responsive usage:

[image]

In detail this means `.ftr-row` has to be 50% height of `.ftr-rows`. I already tried all kinds of stuff like 'absolute positioning', 'displaying as table' etc. How can this be solved?

```
[...]

<!--##############
     LINE 16 HTML 
    ##############-->

      <div class="grid_6 ftr-rows ftr-half">

                <div class="ftr-row">
                    <div class="ftr-row-text">
                        <h1>HEADLINE 1</h1>
                        <hr />
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ftr-row">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/960/475/abstract/1" class="ftr-row-img" />
                </div>

            </div>

[...]
```

http://codepen.io/retober/pen/vLOpVP?editors=110

```
[...]

/* LINE 64 IN CSS */ 
/* HALF WIDTH / HALF HEIGHT */

.ftr-rows {}

.ftr-row {}

.ftr-row-img {}

.ftr-row-text {}

[...]
```

*If possible, I'd like to avoid flexbox but any other mostly compatible solution would be fine.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Already tried that but even absolute positioning cant handle a height of 50% if the size of the parent is undefined.

Comment: Hmmm  yes, of course,

Answer (score 1):

How about using Jquery?

```
var half_height = $(".ftr-rows").height()*(.5)

$(".ftr-row").css("height", half_height)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cc4h10cr/3/

Comment: Looks like a promising solution but your code is not exactly dynamic or responsive. So when i resize my browser window he doesn't resize the container correctly. Running your code on every resize is also not very practical because of the performance.